# Какое значение имеет переменная os.sep?

Tags: python

какую роль переменная os.sep играет в этом скрипте и для чего она нужна? Хотелось бы услышать развернутый ответ, заранее спасибо!

```
import os
import time

source = '"C:\\my documents"'

target_dir = 'D:\\backup\\' 
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, source)

if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия успешно создана в', target)
else:
    print('Создание резервной копии не удалось')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно явно использовать `os.sep` для формирования пути файла. Лучше воспользуйтесь [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

target_dir = 'D:\\backup' 
target = os.path.join(target_dir, f"{DT.now():%Y%m%d%H%M%S}.zip")
```